# send fund to wrong chain

Tags: gnosis-safe

I transferred my funds on Linea to the Safe wallet on the Base chain. I used hexadecimal to gain control of this address on Linea, but I still can't see this wallet on safe.linea.build. Is there any hope in this situation? "I have successfully retrieved it on other chains before, but since the Safe wallet currently does not support the Linea chain, I am not sure if there is still a chance of recovery.

p.s. I retrieve the multi-signature wallet with the same address on the Linea chain by: sending a transaction to 0xa6b71e26c5e0845f74c812102ca7114b6a896ab2, using the same hex data as when created on the Base chain.

Comment: I found that I used the hex on the base chain, but I can't restore the multi-signature wallet with the same name on the linea chain, and I don't know what's going on.